# redirect user using soap service

Tags: php, web-services, redirect, soap, post-redirect-get

I'm trying to create a webservice using **`php`** and **`soap`**.

Assume that I want to redirect user to post office webservice after some stuff.

How should I do this using `php` and `soap`?


I tried :

```
function test()
{
    return //something like php header() function
}
```

**OR**

```
function test()
{
    global $server;
    $server->addSoapHeader("location: http://google.com");
}
```

but both of them are wrong ways.


Would you let me know how should I do this if this is possible?

And if it is possible, can I send some information to another web service, like `GET` method or another soap call?

***Thanks in Advance***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what's your situation but one way to redirect user to another page using soap result is that to send a very simple `html` code in `String` to user, and then the page that give the soap result, will redirect to your goal page.

**Look at this example :**

```
function test() {

    return '<!doctype html><html><head><title>Test<title></head><body> <script>window.location = "http://example.com?q=WHERE"</script></body></html>';

}
```

This will redirect user to another page...

Hope this help you.